# A sufficient condition for the positive definiteness of the symmetric part of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, positive-definite

In Villani's monograph titled "Hypocoercivity" the following is stated without proof: Given a general square matrix $M = (m_{ij})$, a sufficient condition for the symmetric part of $M$ to be positive definite is $$\begin{cases} \forall i,~~~~~~ m_{ii} > 0 \\ \forall (i,j),~i\neq j, \implies m_{ij} <<\sqrt{m_{ii}\,m_{jj}}\end{cases}$$ May I know why these two conditions are enough to deduce the positive definiteness of $\frac 12(M + M^T)$ (which is the symmetric part of $M$)?

Comment: what is the meaning of $<<$ in the second condition?

Comment: @WillJagy The author didn't make that clear, but I guess this is the notation for "much less than"

Comment: meanwhile, the conditions $m_{ij}^2 < m_{ii} m_{jj}$ are necessary for positive definiteness

Comment: do you have a link to the paper?

Comment: @WillJagy I agree that this is the necessary condition, the problem is about sufficiency

Comment: https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0609050.pdf page 32

Comment: I don't see that the double << is defined. On the other hand, it seems that everything follows if the 4 by 4 matrix comes out right. You do need to look at the referred Lemma A.16 in Appendix A.22 for, well, context. Pages 159-160

Comment: And, he calls it a memoir. I suspect the mysterious << line, and other bits, are intended to convey intuition, with precise conditions arrived at in a sort of conversation, perhaps deferred to appendices.

Comment: But still, I need to understand why the above two conditions are "sufficient" for the positive-definiteness. You can think of $<<$ as simply $<$

Comment: if you interpret it to mean $\lt$ then it is **not** a sufficient condition for positive definiteness of $m\times m$ matrices for $m\gt 2$.  E.g.  $M:=\left[\begin{matrix}11 & 5 & 5 & -5\\5 & 11 & -5 & 5\\5 & -5 & 11 & 5\\-5 & 5 & 5 & 11\end{matrix}\right]$  has spectrum (16,16,16,-4) and hence is indefinite yet it satisfies your purported criteria.

Comment: @user8675309 Interesting, what about the condition $\forall (i,j),~i\neq j, \implies m_{ij} \leq \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{m_{ii}\,m_{jj}}$ (this condition is imposed by the author later). By the way, the author is not saying that $M$ is positive definite, but its symmetric part.

Comment: The $M$ I gave before is symmetric, so it is equal to its symmetric part.  This new condition obviously isn't true. My hunch is that the author is trying to use diagonal dominance and not saying so for whatever reason.  Final counter-example  $M:= \left[\begin{matrix}13 & 3 & 3 & -3 & 3 & -3 & -3 & 3\\3 & 13 & -3 & 3 & -3 & 3 & 3 & -3\\3 & -3 & 13 & 3 & -3 & 3 & 3 & -3\\-3 & 3 & 3 & 13 & 3 & -3 & -3 & 3\\3 & -3 & -3 & 3 & 13 & 3 & 3 & -3\\-3 & 3 & 3 & -3 & 3 & 13 & -3 & 3\\-3 & 3 & 3 & -3 & 3 & -3 & 13 & 3\\3 & -3 & -3 & 3 & -3 & 3 & 3 & 13\end{matrix}\right]$.  This has signature $(7,1)$.

Comment: @user8675309 Thanks! Should I understand your example as a indication that the author made a mistake?